# O que há de errado em pedir para que responda a pergunta ao invés de encher linguiça?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, voto-contra

Eu pedi para um determinado usuário responder a minha pergunta, pois ele postou um código que não tinha nada a ver com que eu tinha perguntado.

Em seguida, dei o voto negativo e, quando comentei que estava errado, logo já recebi -1 na minha pergunta.

Em seguida, a resposta foi removida.

Daí quando eu mesmo corri atrás de uma fonte para responder a minha pergunta (já que fui acusado de estar pedindo para codificarem para mim), tomei -1 também na minha resposta, sendo que a fonte é confiável (SOEN) e a resposta lá tá com 57 pontos positivos.

[Detectar ou bloquear redirecionamento com ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102398/detectar-ou-bloquear-redirecionamento-com-ajax)

Eu só queria entender se eu fui hostil, se minha pergunta está errada, se minha resposta está errada.

Enfim, costumava ser ansioso e isso piorava quando eu tomava Coca Cola (tomei dois copos ontem). Mas não acredito que tenha feito um comentário que gerasse essa reação (e nem se tivesse feito, pois o mérito de receber -1 deve ser se a pergunta ou resposta está ruim)

Comment: Correndo o risco de ser mal interpretado pelo usuário citado por você, digo que ele não entende o sistema e se demonstrou agressivo algumas vezes http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102362/problema-acentuação-php-e-mysql#comment209211_102372 aonde acuso os outros de votarem por serem xaropes, mas ele mesmo usa os votos de maneira equivocada e leva as coisas para o lado pessoal, a [resposta do @brasofilo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4644/3635) seria um bom link para mandar para ele...

Comment: ... No caso se notar algum tipo de hostilidade, não entre na onda, mande o link [be-nice](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) pra ele e se ainda ficar nesta então você deve sinalizar para um moderador. Não entre em onda de discutir, assim como os inesperientes devem presumir boa intenção, nós também devemos ser respeitosos mesmo nestes tipos de situações :)

Comment: -1 de vez em quando é o preço de uma participação mais ativa. Exercitar a diplomacia pode evitar alguns desgostos :p

Answer (score 10):

Sim, me parece que você foi um pouco hostil.

Esse trecho -

> Já que alguns demostram hostilidade em responder a minha pergunta

Não faça isso. É irrelevante para a pergunta em si e para a resposta, e polariza as opiniões. Não demande conteúdo - se o que foi oferecido responde então marque como tal, caso não aguarde por mais respostas. No máximo, mostre a quem postou a resposta (na sua opinião) incompleta qual é a sua duvida em específico.

Comment: Nesse ponto eu concordo você. Mas fiquei nervoso na hora com isso! Além de reclamar comigo de ter pedido pra responder à pergunta, ainda tomei -1 (gastei meu tempo pra responder)

Comment: Na verdade não é "Na minha opnião". Você colar um código que está na documentação do jquery e dizer "Vê se isso resolve o seu problema" não é uma solução nem de longe.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sempre que você perceber que está nervoso, acalme-se. ;) E, sim, se você acha que a resposta é incompleta, esta é sua opinião - você pode apresentar então documentação de suporte que prove sua opinião. Para fins de correlação, minha opinião é que a teoria da relatividade está basicamente correta. ;)

Comment: lbotinelly e @WallaceMaxters - Se notar em outra postagem o tal usuário citado é um pouco encrenqueiro :p ao menos é o que me pareceu, vejam:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102362/problema-acentuação-php-e-mysql#comment209211_102372 - não estou dizendo que é um cara mal, só estou dizendo que ele compreende errado o sistema :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tive a mesma impressão nesta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102346/aba-n%C3%A3o-vem-aberta/102349#102349 que eu apenas comentei a solução dele e recebi downvote na minha o.O